# How do I get information from a table in lua?

Tags: lua, iteration

I have some lua code like this:

```lua
_table = {
  stuff = {
    item1 = {Name="Stack",Rarity="Over"};
    item2 = {Name="Flow",Rarity="Com"}
  };
};

print("placeholder") -- example thing
_stuff = _table.stuff
for i = 1, #_stuff do
 print(_stuff[i].Name)
end
```

The output is this:
`placeholder`

I've tried to look at stuff but I don't think it was related to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lua tables conceptually are "maps": They map keys to values. Your table `_table` maps the key `stuff` to the `{item1 = ..., item2 = ...}` table. Your `stuff` table maps the string `"item1"` to the `{Name="Stack",Rarity="Over"}` table and the string `"item2"` to the `{Name="Flow",Rarity="Com"}` table.

The length operator `#` completely ignores string keys. It returns an integer `i` such that `t[i] ~= nil and t[i+1] == nil`. In particular, it returns `0` if there are no integer keys in the table. This is the case for your `stuff` table: You only have string keys. Thus your loop never runs, as the limit is `0` and `i = 1 > 0` already is the case before the first loop iteration.

Put simply, you're **trying to iterate over a "dictionary" (a table with string keys) as if it were a list**. Lua tables have both a "list part" (integer keys from `1` to `n`, where usually `n = #t`) and a "hash part" (of all other keys). The "list part" is empty in your case, so there's nothing for you to iterate over.

To iterate over *all* key-value pairs of any table (list or dictionary) in an undefined order, use [`pairs`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-pairs) (rather than `ipairs` or iterating over indices `i`, which only works for lists):

```lua
for itemname, item in pairs(_stuff) do
    print(item.Name)
end
```

If you want a defined order of iteration, either build a second table of keys...

```lua
local order = {"item1", "item2"}
for _, key in ipairs(order) do
    print(_stuff[key].Name)
end
```

... or use the integer keys ("list part") of the table:

```lua
_table = {
  stuff = {
    {key = "item1", Name="Stack", Rarity="Over"};
    {key = "item2", Name="Flow", Rarity="Com"};
  };
};

_stuff = _table.stuff
for _, key in ipairs(order) do
    for i = 1, #_stuff do
        print(_stuff[i].Name)
    end
end
```

then works as expected.